# Django Upload file get full name and file path

Tags: python, django, google-api, django-forms, dropbox-api

I'm tinkering around with cloud storage api's and need help getting the full file name from an upload form on Django. I currently can let the user choose a file, "file.txt" from any directory, and can get the name through

```
for file in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    print file.name `
```

However I want the full file path, something more like `'home/user/documents/file.txt'`

Is this possible and how would I get the full name? I'm not looking to actually upload the file, just get the full path so that I can utilize dropbox/google drive api.

For reference here is my **form**:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    folder_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 300)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django FILES upload: path and filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993413/django-files-upload-path-and-filename)

Comment: I've seen this^, however does this mean there is no way to utilize dropbox or google drive's api outside of having a user type in the full path of the file name, selecting a filename within their CWD, or uploading the file to a known location and the pushing it to dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not tell what directory the files come from.
They do not even give that information to the scripts on the page.

When a user uploads a file, you may know:

- Its basename.
- Its size.
- Its type (usually guessed from extension).
- Its modification time.

This is all you will get, regardless of whether you access the information straight from the browser's `<input>` element, or wait for it to `POST` it.

You may also turn this answer the other way around: if you really need to be able to post the full path of the file, you need to develop a client-side application that will send it. It could be a standalone executable, a browser addon/app, or a Java applet, whatever as long as it runs outside of the webpage sandbox.

I do not use dropbox, but I believe you need to download and install some additional software to use it. That's how it would access the full path of your files.